# Python element tree xml parsing to create object

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, elementtree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [module to create python object representation from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306671/module-to-create-python-object-representation-from-xml)
>   [Best way to parse xml in Appengine with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628771/best-way-to-parse-xml-in-appengine-with-python)

Can anyone point me in the right direction for doing the following:

-I have an xml file and xsd

-I'm using python and element tree

-I already validated the xml against the xsd

-I want to know, what are good ways of creating objects from the xml? I want to read the xml, and create an object (based on the tag) add the info to the object, and then hopefully put that object in the database.

Any links or ideas to get appreciated. (I'm using google app engine too)

Comment: Can you give a short, concrete example of what you mean by "creating objects from the xml"?

Comment: I just found this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628771/best-way-to-parse-xml-in-appengine-with-python][1]

thanks anyway.